# Change maximum concurrent tasks in a GCP Cloud Tasks queue

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

I'd like to know how to change the maximum number of concurrent tasks in a queue. I know that this can somehow be done in the yaml files, but is this possible using gcloud commands from the terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following command to set the [maximum number](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/configuring-queues#rate) of concurrent tasks:

```
gcloud tasks queues update [QUEUE_ID] \
--max-dispatches-per-second=[DISPATCH_RATE] \
--max-concurrent-dispatches=[MAX_RUNNING]
```

To only set the maximum number:

```
gcloud tasks queues update QUEUE \
--max-concurrent-dispatches=20
```